# Recursive call with an iterator crashes

Tags: c++, recursion, vector, iterator

I'm trying to go through a vector of strings with an iterator, but it needs to check a few values in advance. I tried doing this with the following code:

```
typedef std::vector<std::string>::iterator Cursor;

std::string check(Cursor& at) {
    int number;
    std::string ans = *at;
    if (ans.empty()) {
        return "NOT OK";
    } else {
        std::stringstream ss(ans);
        ss >> number >> ans;
        if (ans == "NOT OK") {
            return "NOT OK";
        } else if (ans == "VALUE") {
            int x;
            ss >> x;
            std::string result("OK");
            for (Cursor c = at; x > 0; ++c, --x) {
                result = check(c);
            }
            return result;
        } else {
            return "OK";
        }
    }
}
```

But this code crashes when it enters the for-loop and I have no idea why.

Comment: You should always compile with warnings enabled. Then the compiler would have warned you that you're using x without assigning a value to it (x is uninitialized).

Comment: @bennofs it was a typo. It still crashes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int x; 
ss >> x; // Here you should check whether x has the expected value.
std::string result("OK");
for (Cursor c = at; x > 0; ++c, --x) { // here you do not check whether c is within boundaries.
  result = check(c);
}

// c should start from at+1, otherwise it may result in infinite recursion.
// Also, termination condition should be added.
for (Cursor c = at+1; x > 0 && c != myVec.end(); ++c, --x) {
```

Comment: I've already checked if x is the expected value, and it is. But I didn't use at+1, which was the solution I needed. Thanks!